# Plotting animated quivers in Python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to animate a vector such as wind in Python. I tried to use quiver function in pylab and in combination with matplotlib.animation from matplotlib. However, the result says `'QuiverKey' object is not subscriptable`. I think that it is because I don't understand fully about these two functions or just these two functions don't match together. Below is my code, it is actually the combination between quiver and animation functions from matplotlib.

```
def update_line(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[...,:num])
    return line,

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,2*np.pi,.2),np.arange(0,2*np.pi,.2) )  
U = np.cos(X)
V = np.sin(Y)

fig1 = plt.figure()
Q = quiver( X[::3, ::3], Y[::3, ::3], U[::3, ::3], V[::3, ::3],
        pivot='mid', color='r', units='inches' )
data = quiverkey(Q, 0.5, 0.03, 1, r'$1 \frac{m}{s}$', fontproperties={'weight': 'bold'})
plt.axis([-1, 7, -1, 7])
title('scales with plot width, not view')
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-') 
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('test')
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, 25, fargs=(data, l),
interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well, `data` is a `QuiverKey` object - it represents a key to a quiver plot, not an array of values that you can index into. I really don't understand what you're aiming for - you say you want to draw animated quivers, but your animation function looks like it's meant to just adds points to a line. Can you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi ali_m, I really appreciate your comment and help. My aim is to create an animation which quivers are moving into the directions of arrows. Maybe my understanding of this function structure is too low. Would you help me to understand how I make each quiver moving into each arrow (vector) direction?

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you mean. Do you want to change the lengths and angles of the arrows, or do you want to move their pivot points around? As far as I'm aware, there is no way to change the x,y coordinates of a quiver plot once it has been created, but you can use `Q.set_UVC()` to update the arrow vectors.

Comment: Thanks ali_m. That Q.set_UVC() may be helpful for my aim. I really appreciate. I will try that function.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's an example to get you started:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

X, Y = np.mgrid[:2*np.pi:10j,:2*np.pi:5j]
U = np.cos(X)
V = np.sin(Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, pivot='mid', color='r', units='inches')

ax.set_xlim(-1, 7)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 7)

def update_quiver(num, Q, X, Y):
    """updates the horizontal and vertical vector components by a
    fixed increment on each frame
    """

    U = np.cos(X + num*0.1)
    V = np.sin(Y + num*0.1)

    Q.set_UVC(U,V)

    return Q,

# you need to set blit=False, or the first set of arrows never gets
# cleared on subsequent frames
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_quiver, fargs=(Q, X, Y),
                               interval=50, blit=False)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: At least in python 3.8, `blit=True` works properly.