# Animating quiver in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I followed some suggested code in response to this question, [Plotting animated quivers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329039/plotting-animated-quivers-in-python), but I'm finding I have a problem that one did not address.  consider the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def ufield(x,y,t):
    return np.cos(x+y)*np.sin(t)

def vfield(x,y,t):
    return np.sin(x+y)*np.cos(t)

x = np.linspace(0,10, num=11)
y = np.linspace(0,10, num=11)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
t = np.linspace(0,1)

def update_quiver(j, ax, fig):
    u = ufield(X,Y,t[j])
    v = vfield(X,Y,t[j])
    Q.set_UVC(u, v)
    ax.set_title('$t$ = '+ str(t[j]))
    return Q,

fig =plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
u = ufield(X,Y,t[0])
v = vfield(X,Y,t[0])
Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, u, v)
ax.set_title('$t$ = '+ str(t[0]))
ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_quiver, 
                              frames = range(0,t.size),
                              interval=1,fargs=(ax, fig))
plt.show()
```

This code runs fine, without a problem.  But, if I want to use an init_func, and I do, because I want to do more with my animation, I tried:

```
def init_quiver():
    u = ufield(X,Y,t[0])
    v = vfield(X,Y,t[0])
    Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, u, v)
    ax.set_title('$t$ = '+ str(t[0]))
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
    return  Q,
```

remove these lines from the main body of the script

```
u = ufield(X,Y,t[0]) 
v = vfield(X,Y,t[0]) 
Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, u, v)
```

and update the animation lines as follows:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_quiver, 
                              frames = range(0,t.size),
                              init_func=init_quiver,
                              interval=1,fargs=(ax, fig))
plt.show()
```

But when I run this, I see the first frame, and nothing ever updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your script, I see the behaviour you describe, and in the terminal where I run it, I get an error with a Traceback ending:

> ```
>  File "quiv.py", line 21, in update_quiver
> Q.set_UVC(u, v)
> NameError: global name 'Q' is not defined
> ```

You can rectify this by adding the line

```
global Q
```

as the first line of your `init_quiver` function.

The complete code now reads:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def ufield(x,y,t):
    return np.cos(x+y)*np.sin(t)

def vfield(x,y,t):
    return np.sin(x+y)*np.cos(t)

x = np.linspace(0,10, num=11)
y = np.linspace(0,10, num=11)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
t = np.linspace(0,1)

def update_quiver(j, ax, fig):
    u = ufield(X,Y,t[j])
    v = vfield(X,Y,t[j])
    Q.set_UVC(u, v)
    ax.set_title('$t$ = '+ str(t[j]))
    return Q,

def init_quiver():
    global Q
    u = ufield(X,Y,t[0])
    v = vfield(X,Y,t[0])
    Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, u, v)
    ax.set_title('$t$ = '+ str(t[0]))
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
    return  Q,

fig =plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_title('$t$ = '+ str(t[0]))
ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_quiver, 
                              frames = range(0,t.size),
                              init_func=init_quiver,
                              interval=1,fargs=(ax, fig))
plt.show()
```

Comment: That works, except, and I'm sorry this was unclear in the original post, if I use the init_func, then I would not have the lines: u = ufield(X,Y,t[0])
v = vfield(X,Y,t[0])
Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, u, v)
in the main body of the script.

Comment: Ah, I see. in that case, you probably have a scoping issue.  Do you seen an error something like "NameError: global name 'Q' is not defined" ?

Comment: What I advise next depends on how bothered you are about tightly controlling scope.  If you are not too bothered - simply add the first line `global Q` to your `init_quiver` function.

Comment: If that works and it's what you want to do - let me know and I'll update the code in the answer to remove the `u`,`v` and `Q` from the main body of code and add that line to the init func

Comment: Edited question and answer to suit the new information provided in comments.  Let me know if it works - either in comments or via vote / accept :)

Comment: @user2379888 just pinging to check whether this worked for you?  Would appreciate vote / accept if it helped you out