# Animate Quiver plot from values in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, animation, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Hi im trying to make an animation of a quiver plot from data in my data frame

I have data stored like this in a pandas DataFrame, somewhat like this

```
    QuivXLoc    QuivYLoc    QuivXVal    QuivYVal    QuivColorVal    QuivPlotNum
0   -70.22     -127.241     1.624       -0.879      1.846623        1
1   -61.74     -127.241     -0.973      -0.027      0.973375        1
2   -65.98     -121.835     0.046       2.416       2.416438        1
3   -74.46     -121.835     -0.151      2.673       2.677262        1
4   -78.70     -116.429     1.073       -0.954      1.435773        2
```

I am currently plotting it like this, and it generates seperate plots for each sequence number perfectly.

```
for seq in quidf['QuivPlotNum'].unique():
    temp=quidf[quidf['QuivPlotNum']==seq]  ## make subset to plot
    plt.quiver(temp['QuivXLoc'], temp['QuivYLoc'], temp['QuivXVal'], temp['QuivYVal'],        # data
           temp['QuivColorVal'],                   # colour the arrows based on this array
           cmap=cm.jet,     # colour map
           headlength=3)        # length of the arrows
```

Theres some additional code to format the plot that I left out.

What I'd like to do is animate the sequence based on iterating through the Sequence number in my data frame. All the examples I saw for Quiver Animation involved scaling previous function by some scalar that is incremented.

**example of similar quiver animation I'd like to generate, I have tried but cannot figure out how to change update_quiver to work for my application:**
[Plotting animated quivers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329039/plotting-animated-quivers-in-python)

Comment: Do you mean animating the quiver arrows growing to their final length? What have you tried?

Comment: yes like in this example the animation shows quiver plot changing by frames. but it is updating based on a scalar. I want to plot based on data stored in the DataFrame  .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329039/plotting-animated-quivers-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `matplotlib.animation` module and its `FuncAnimation` class:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd

# read in the date and group it by the frame number
data = pd.read_csv('data2.csv', index_col=0)
grouped = data.groupby('QuivPlotNum')

# set up the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(-200, 200)
ax.set_ylim(-200, 200)

# create empty plot for the update function to manipulate
plot = ax.quiver([], [], [], [], [], cmap='jet', headlength=3)

# create an iterator over the group, next() will return a tuple
# of QuivPlotNum, DataFrame
iterator = iter(grouped)

def update(i):
    # get next thing in the iterator
    key, data = next(iterator)
    # set new x, y coordinates for the plot
    plot.set_offsets(np.column_stack([data.QuivXLoc, data.QuivYLoc]))
    # update vector and color values
    plot.set_UVC(data.QuivXVal, data.QuivYVal, data.QuivColorVal)

# create the animation, update every 1000 ms
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=1000)

# show it
plt.show()
```